# HTTP Post to test WCF REST End Point. Using an XML formatted contract

Tags: wcf, rest, unit-testing, http

I have a webservice with a contract that is required to use XML. 
(It has other JSON decorated contracts and they are consumed fine by the users)

I want  to test the XML contract via the REST endpoint. (It works fine from a unit test using the default SOAP context)
My efforts of using a roll your own Http Post in a unit test  give Error 400

After about 3 days and the test code looking like a bomb site I am still stuck.

How hard can it be???

VS2013 FrameWork 4.5.1.

**All I am trying to do is prove with the unit test (or Fiddler or Postman) that the  REST endpoint will handle a Post with an xml payload.**

If someone could put up some sample  HTTP POST c# code that they expect to consume the simple test contract below I would be grateful. I have tried more variations of what is available on the Net than I can remember and am now totally confused.

**TEST CONTRACT:**

```
[WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "Testing",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    void Testing(TestData test);
```

This is implemented by:

```
 public void Testing(TestData test)
    {
        int x = test.MyInt;
        string y = test.MyString;
    }


 [DataContract]
public class TestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

The unit test code is:

```
                string url = "http://myService.svc/REST/Testing";
            DellbertCouponParking.TestData t = new DellbertCouponParking.TestData();
            t.MyInt = 2;
            t.MyString = "HelloWorld";

            XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DellbertCouponParking.TestData));
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, t);
            string xml = sw.ToString();

            byte[] formData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url))
                                     as HttpWebRequest;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = formData.Length;
            req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            // Send the request:
            using (Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            // Pick up the response:
            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                          as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader =
                    // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
                    new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(result.Length > 0);
```

There are  'JSON' contracts that the REST Endpoint is servicing OK.
This is my first attempt at an xml contract.

Since my original posting of this question, I have proven that the testing code is OK by posting to httpbin.org/post

So I guess my problem comes down to:

- Possible bad decoration of the contract
- Web Site configuration. (Internal test server)

Further information:

The web.config holds:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://sec.paymentexpress.com/PxF/pxf.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPxFusion"
    contract="DPSFusion.IPxFusion" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPxFusion" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
        maxArrayLength="200000000" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPxFusion" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxBufferSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
        maxArrayLength="200000000" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="JsonBinding" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
        maxArrayLength="200000000" />
    </binding>       
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="CouponParkingWCF.CouponService">
    <endpoint name="SoapEndPoint" address="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" />
    <endpoint name="JSON" address="REST" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CouponParkingWCF.ICouponService" />       
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>        
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<!-- <protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The IIS Log shows:
2015-07-20 23:13:25 192.168.0.235 POST /wsCouponParking/CouponParking.svc/REST/Testing - 80 - 192.168.0.38 - - 400 0 0 203

Would appreciate any guidance on what I am missing.
Thanks
bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much unbridled frustration I have the answer. 
Absolute hatred to Microsoft at the moment for allowing such a flimsy construction into the wild.
We are not all xml and endpoint experts and I for one expected consistent behavior between WCF Contracts decorated for Json and XML endpoints.

You make umpteen service and data contracts using JSON then you think you will just change the decoration slightly for the XML service contract and it'll roll out the door. Yeah Right!

Rant over.

Four parts to answer:

1) Get a decent chunk for your Web.config that handles XML and JSON endpoints.
My undying thanks to Satchi who posted this as an answer to question *WCF REST return single method as JSON and XML*

```
<endpoint address="XML" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingXML" contract="xxxxxx.Ixxxxxxx" behaviorConfiguration="RestXMLEndpointBehavior"/>
<endpoint address="JSON" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJSON" contract="xxxxxxxx.Ixxxxxxxxx" behaviorConfiguration="RestJSONEndpointBehavior"/>

<endpointBehaviors>

  <behavior name="RestJSONEndpointBehavior">
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
  </behavior>
  <behavior name="RestXMLEndpointBehavior">
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
  </behavior>

</endpointBehaviors>        
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="webHttpBindingXML"/>
  <binding name="webHttpBindingJSON"/>
</webHttpBinding>
```

2) Add the NameSpace attribute to the  [DataContract] decoration **this is essential.**
Can't remember where I found this is my wandering around the net but thanks to whoever posted it.

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "")]//The Namespace attribute is essential.
public class TestData
{

    [DataMember]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

3) Remove the decoration off the service contract. Again thanks to Satchi.

```
 //[WebInvoke(
    //    Method = "POST",
    //    UriTemplate = "Testing",
    //    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    //    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    //    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    void Testing(TestData test);
```

4) Make use of the help page that is provided when you use the above Web.config addition. This mollifies my hatred somewhat, a great feature. 
e.g. http://myserver/myProject/myService.svc/XML/help/
This will show you the correct structure for an example XML body for your test request.

I am using Framework 4.5.1 for the WCF project and still needed this solution.